# Faster file writing on sshfs mounted directory

Tags: linux, mount, sshfs

Here is the following scenario: I have **server1** and **server2** and using **sshfs** I mount a directory from **server2** on **server1**, let's say */mnt*.
Now, if I try to unpack a 50K files archive on **server1:/mnt** it takes 13 mins to complete while doing the same on **server1:/local_dir** will only take some 5 seconds.

I was wondering if there is any way/configuration that could speed up the things.

Answer (score 1):

It's slower since it has to unpack them to a remote server. The speed difference is due to network delay, sshfs overhead, etc. For every file, you have to send the data to server2, wait for response, and then do it again for the next.

If you want to speed it up a bit*, upload the package to server1:/mnt and unpack it on server2.

*it will still be slower then on server1:/local_dir ofcourse

Comment: yes, I know it will be faster but I need to unpack it on the server1 :D

Comment: Maybe try with nfs? It's a bit faster than ssh, but requires additional configuration, and could pose a security risk if not configured properly... but it will still be slower then local unpack.